# logs getting written in backup file instead of main file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j2.xml in 2 applications and both to log in same info.log. Size of log file mentioned in application A and B is 100KB. When info.log exceeds 100KB info.log.1 backup file gets created. When application B tries to log, logs are getting written in info.log.1 instead of info.log. When i restart application B then logs are getting logged in info.log. Why this bizarre way of logging is observed and what's the solution for this. Below is the log4j2.xml of application B

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="5">
<!-- Logging Properties -->
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS} [%p] %c, %m%n</Property>
    <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">/logs</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" /> </Console>
    <!-- File Appenders on need basis -->
    <RollingFile name="infoLog" fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/info.log" filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}%-i.log">
        <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="INFO" maxLevel="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20KB" /> </Policies>
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="50" /> </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="errorlog" fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/info.log" filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}%-i.log">
        <LevelRangeFilter minLevel="ERROR" maxLevel="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100KB" /> </Policies>
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" />
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" /> </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="infoLog" />
        <AppenderRef ref="errorlog" level="error" /> </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the behaviour comes since you have two applications with their own log4j configuration each, and you are running on a Un*xish system.

In Linux, if you have one application writing to a file it opens a file handle to that item on disk. If you at the same time rename the file and create a new one with the old name, the file handle in the directory changes but not the one in memory for that application. So the application does not notice the change and keeps writing to the same item on disk - you notice it as the data is still appended to the renamed file.

That's why log rotation either requires some tricks (read more about [logrotate](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-logrotate/) command), or you perform log rotation on application level - in Log4j it would be done via the [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.html).

Since you have two applications writing to the same logfile you have the situation that whichever one of the two applications decides to rotate the logs, the other one does not notice as I described above. Better have separate logfiles for the different applications.

Comment: Additionally the configuration file tries to create two different appenders logging to the same file. Theoretically that should create two appenders sharing the same `RollingFileManager` with a random triggering and rollover policy (probably the first one).

Comment: Hmmm, what's the use of two appenders with almost the same configuration? That is strange indeed.